# facebook share image

Tags: facebook-api

Фейсбук отображает не ту картинку что надо.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://САЙТ/КАРТИНКА.jpg"/>
```

не работает. 
Сделал так :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://САЙТ/КАРТИНКА.jpg"/> 
<link rel="image_src" href="http://САЙТ/КАРТИНКА.jpg" />
```

теперь в дебаггере - https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/
отображает в og:image 2 картинки, зато правильные!
Но! Картинка которая шейрится, все равно не та...

Вот ссылка, для примера, чтоб посмотреть в дебаггере.
Буду благодарен вашей помощи!

http://grushevskogo5.com/sobitiya/glavnye-sobytiya-oseni/

Comment: У них кэш работает, но его можно чистить. Примеры можно посмотреть [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776567)

Comment: Гхмм, а при чем тут кеш?
(почистил, без толку)

Comment: А, понял что не так. Мне показалось, что вы сменили картинки и теперь отображает старые, а не новые. А вам надо просто другую картинку показать, так же?

Comment: Да. Чтоб оно показывало правильно.
Сейчас на их дебаггере показывает что в og:image - 2 картинки, нужные!
А шейрится все равно не та.

Comment: А картинка, которая показывается сейчас, использовалась раньше? Или она туда сама попала? Добавив простые get-параметры я вообще картинку не вижу. Может для начала стоит исправить ошибки "Meta Tags In Body"?

Comment: Эти мета теги в head я всунуть не смогу.
Картинка там рендомная со странички подтягивается.

Comment: Кстати, а шарится-то именно та картинка, которая нужна, просто при шаринге показывается левая. Может, правда, все дело в кэше?

Comment: Хмм, а как Вы узнали какая шарится? Я когда писал шарится имел ввиду - показывается .
Да чистил, не помогает(

Comment: Судя по всему причина именно в этом - метатеги не там где они должны быть. А все, что показывает - это он предполагает (`Based on the raw tags, we constructed the following Open Graph properties`) И про картинку вашу говорит: `og:image was not defined, could not be downloaded or was not big enough. Please define a chosen image using the og:image metatag, and use an image that's at least 200x200px and is accessible from Facebook. Image '...164200.jpg' will be used instead. Consult http://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler for more troubleshooting tips.`

Comment: Сделал, теперь og:image распознает правильно, когда делишься записью, тоже правильно отображает, но, при нажатии "поделиться" - неправильная картинка(( 
Проблема в том, что когда люди ссылку кидают друг другу в фб в сообщениях, то картинка неправильная (
Вот пример незакешированой - http://grushevskogo5.com/verhovnaya_rada/syumar-budet-kurirovat-izbiratelnyy-shtab-bpp/